# How to select, update and insert rows from a table to itself?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-id

I have an exam table with the following columns

```
CLASS_EXAM_ID
CLASS_ID
EXAM_NAME
TermNo
WEIGHT
FROM_DATE
TO_DATE
EXAM_DATE
```

where `CLASS_EXAM_ID` is a unique id.

I want to copy term 1 and just make term 2. I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO Exam (ExamId, ClassId, Term, TermNo, Weight,Fromdate,Todate,ExamDate)
SELECT 
  'ExamId00001'AS EXPR1, 
  ClassId, 
  'Term 2' AS EXPR2,
  TermNo,
  Weight,
  Fromdate,
  ToDate,
  ExamDate
FROM Exam 
WHERE Term = 'Term 1'
```

How do I change `ExamId` for each row of data selected?

Comment: Please edit your question to REMOVE THE SHOUTING.

Comment: You just need to `UPDATE`, not `INSERT` if you want to **change**  only the `Term` but it seems like you are trying to alter the table altogether by adding another column, `Term`, which isn't in your original `Exam` table. You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how `ExamId` field is defined in this table. If it is an Unique ID the best way is to define is as [auto incremented key field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). In this case just use following INSERT statement without `ExamId` and SQL Server will insert unique Id's automatically.

```
INSERT INTO Exam (ClassId, Term, TermNo, Weight,Fromdate,Todate,ExamDate)
SELECT 
   ClassId, 
  'Term 2' AS EXPR2,
  TermNo,
  Weight,
  Fromdate,
  ToDate,
  ExamDate
FROM Exam 
WHERE Term = 'Term 1'
```